Gazebo Simulator is very laggy and keeps going blank
I am new to using Gazebo but it is proving to be very hard to use. When I'm loading in a model, it's always super laggy, which I can deal with, but for some reason, every few seconds the screen goes blank. I have a simple file which just loads in a box and a plane, but even that seems to not work properly. Here is a link to a video of my screen. Can anyone tell me why this is happening? Perhaps I downloaded it wrong, or is my computer too weak to handle gazebo?

It may be worth a reinstall just to see if it repeats.
What does your system monitor say for your CPU usage? That may give an indication if it is maxing out your computer.

Yeah I just deleted it and installed gazebo-11 instead of gazebo-ignition, and that one seems to be working fine. I don't remember what Task Manager said about the cpu usage for Gazebo but it may also be an issue with the fact that I am using a built in GPU, which is rather weak compared to nvidia gpus
